# Specifying new trajectory when old trajectory already running- `ur_modern_driver`

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, ur10, ur-driver, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a trajectory running on the UR10 (in URSim) with 3 points. I'd like to interrupt and send new trajectory commands. I get an error:

> Goal start doesn't match current pose

I looked into : https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/36

A possible way to solve this is by specifying the `time_from_start` as non-zero value. How do I get the current time to make sure the current pose is considered as first point of the trajectory. I tried `time_from_start=rospy.Duration(rospy.Time.now()))` but it doesn't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285125/specifying-new-trajectory-when-old-trajectory-already-running--%60ur_modern_driver%60/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're trying to do can't work (at least not with current `HEAD` of `ur_modern_driver`): the driver checks a few constraints upon receiving a new goal and one of them is whether the first trajectory point in the trajectory is sufficiently close to the 'current pose' of the robot ([here](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/blob/9397f47ac158fe5976719f33101334371bc15d44/src/ur_ros_wrapper.cpp#L347-L353)).

> A possible way to solve this is by specifying the `time_from_start` as non-zero value.

As [ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver#36](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/36) explains, this check does not depend on time, but on the joint angles of the robot at the time the goal is received.

I'm not sure how setting the `time_from_start` to some value will influence this.

---

Edit: *trajectory replacement* (which is sort of the 'official' name for what you are trying to do) *is* supported by the `joint_trajectory_controller` of `ros_control`. `ur_modern_driver` has support for `ros_control` (and that side of the driver does not include the 'start state check'), however that comes with its own set of constraints and requirements.

You could look into that, but please carefully review the open issues.

---

Edit2: you may also want to take a look at [ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver#120](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/pull/120), which is a candidate upgrade of `ur_modern_driver`, and [Zagitta/ur_modern_driver#9](https://github.com/Zagitta/ur_modern_driver/pull/9), which is an upgrade / extension of that.

`Zagitta/ur_modern_driver#9` does not influence `ros_control` performance / compatibility at all.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-12**:
Thanks! @gvdhoorn